# problems with LAG function (SAS)

Tags: sas

I am using SAS Base V9.4

I have daily balances each of my customers and i want to find out if they increases or decreases their balance from one  day to another. So I wrote the following  code but i am receiving following Error.

> "ERROR 72-185: The LAG function call has too many arguments."

```
IF LAG(CUST_ID,1)=CUST_ID AND (BALANCE - LAG(BALANCE,1))>0 THEN FLAG="FLAG=1"
```

what could be the problem?

Comment: try using lag1(cust_id) instead of lag(cust_id,1), same for balance

Comment: You can also use the `DIF` function instead `LAG` to calculate the difference between the current and previous value (i.e. `DIF(BALANCE)>0`).  Your `IF` statement should work ok here, but be careful using `IF` with `LAG`.  `IFN` is generally a preferable option for the reasons explained [here](http://www.howles.com/saspapers/CC33.pdf)

Comment: Avoid lag completely and use `retain`.

Answer (score 3):

The depth of the lag is part of the function name and not an argument. So you want `LAG1(BALANCE)` instead of `LAG(BALANCE,1)`.  `LAG1()` can be shortened to `LAG()`.  Also add a BY statement if you want to process your data BY customer. This will create `FIRST.` and `LAST.` variables.  You should also look at the `DIF()` series of functions if you just want the difference and not the actual previous value.

```
data want ;
  set have ;
  by cust_id;
  if dif(balance) > 0 and not first.cust_id then flag='FLAG=1' ;
```

Comment: by cust_id and date to be sure of the order